# How to keep making ajax calls for multiple forms in a step wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a plugin to create a wizard (steps). Currently I need to send an ajax call on every step (when leaving the step). I've had an issue that it kept sending infinite ajax calls, so I built in a check if an ajax call was already made but now it won't send any ajax calls past the first step.

How can I change that?

This is my code:

```
var ajaxInvoke = false;
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
  if(ajaxInvoke == false){
    ajaxInvoke = true;

    var form_data = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:form_data,
      success:function(data){
         // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
         $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
      }
    });
    // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event
    return false;
  }
});
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="step-0" class="">
  <form id="step_0_form" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="formateninput form-control" name="aantal" value="1" min="1">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="step-1" class="">
  <form id="step_2_form" method="post">
    <input type="number" class="formateninput form-control" name="hoogte" value="100" min="60">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="step-2" class="">
  <form id="step_3_form" method="post">
      <input type="radio" id="Hout" name="Materiaal" value="Hout" >
      <input type="radio" id="Debond" name="Materiaal" value="Debond">
  </form>
</div>
```

I can see in my network tab it posts the first step, but when clicking next there are no more ajax calls after the first one.

Comment: Note you dont set `ajaxInvoke` back to `false` when the ajax call is finished (ie in the callback). Probably why it never gets called again, change that and see if that solves your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reset the bool flag you have set, maybe like so :

```
$.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
  data:form_data,
  success:function(data){
     // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
     $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
  },
  complete: function(){ ajaxInvoke = false; }
});
```

This way, when the ajax is completed, failed or success, the variable will be reset and the next ajax will be able to be sent

Comment: Thanks this does send multiple calls, but the second call is empty. Only when I go the the third step and then click on the second step again, the data of the second step is posted correctly. Any idea why that is?

Comment: What do you mean by this? form_data is empty for #step_2_form ?

Comment: Yes, in my network tab I see for the first step: `aantal: 1` but when I leave the second step, an ajax call is made but nothing is posted. Only when I go back from step 3 to step 2, step 2 is posted with the correct input values.

Comment: Is `stepNumber` 0-based on this widget? are you sure the stepNumber corresponds to the form's ids?

Comment: My bad I just checked the html, yes they have to be the same and one form id wasn't. I fixed it now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The variable remains the same as the value you assigned(ajaxInvoke = true)
if you want to use a variable in your code;

```
    var ajaxInvoke = false;
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, anchorObject, stepNumber, stepDirection) {
  if(ajaxInvoke == false){
    ajaxInvoke = true;

    var form_data = $("#step_"+ stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:form_data,
      success:function(data){
         // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
         ajaxInvoke = false;
         $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
      }
    });
    // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the resetting of the variable mentioned by other users, check to see when and how many times the event is being triggered, also try to push a single object with your event functions:

```
var ajaxInvoke = false;

var evtOptions = {
   'anchorObject' : anchorObject,
   'stepNumber' : stepNumber,
   'stepDirection' : stepDirection
}

$("#smartwizard").off("leaveStep");
$("#smartwizard").on("leaveStep", function(e, evtOptions) {
  if(ajaxInvoke == false){
    ajaxInvoke = true;

    var form_data = $("#step_"+ evtOptions.stepNumber +"_form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
      data:form_data,
      success:function(data){
         // indicate the ajax has been done, release the next step
         ajaxInvoke = false;
         $("#smartwizard").smartWizard("next");
      }
    });
    // Return false to cancel the `leaveStep` event
    return false;
  }
});
```

also just as a general working practice, 
I recommend using the `$(document)` as your event bus as using page elements sometimes bring up weird edge cases

Also when setting an event listener always remove it with and `$().off()` to avoid complications